# Como calcular a diferença entre valores que estão na mesma coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de calcular a diferença entre valores que estão na mesma coluna. Por exemplo: tenho uma tabela com 2 campos: data e saldo. Preciso adicionar um novo campo, contendo a diferença de saldo de uma data para outra.

```
Dia        Saldo      Variação
------------------------------
01/12 ---  10 ------- 0  
02/12 ---  30 ------- 20  
03/12 ---  70 ------- 40  
04/12 ---  80 ------- 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT 
    m.id,
    m.data,
    m.saldo,
    IFNULL(saldo - (SELECT mt.saldo FROM movimento mt WHERE mt.id < m.id ORDER BY mt.id DESC LIMIT 0,1), 0) AS variacao
FROM movimento m
```

Dá uma olhada no [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06289/1)

Comment: Pode usar até o próprio campo data para comparação e ordenação em vez de Id (que não aparece no exemplo e pode nem ser sequencial). Bacana a solução. +1

Comment: Com certeza, desde que haja apenas um movimento por data

Comment: Neste caso é apenas um registro por data mesmo. Muito obrigado! Só não entendi como resolver fazendo apenas a comparação entre datas, sem o uso de id.

Comment: @samuelgp Exatamente do mesmo jeito - no comando apenas troque campo `id` pelo campo `dia`.

Comment: Esse limit no sql server ficaria como ?

Answer (score -1):

Conheço duas opções, você traz isso em uma consulta como em [Calculo entre campos](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/527066-calculo-entre-campos-e-possivel/)

`SELECT ValorBoleto + TotalJuros AS Preco FROM fotoprodutos`

ou este [Fórmula em SQL (inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582614/how-to-insert-some-formula-in-mysql)

`SELECT
    name,
    black,
    yellow,
    white,
    qty_job
    (SUM(black) + SUM(yellow) + SUM(white)*0.4) / qty_job AS total
FROM counter
GROUP BY name;`

Outra opção é você fazer isso via linguagem de programação. Quando você for salvar, você calcula o campo antes de preenchê-lo. Mas neste caso, precisaríamos de saber a linguagem de programação para ajudá-lo melhor.

Comment: Nesse caso específico precisa-se de um cálculo "entre linhas", e não "entre campos".

Comment: Diz-se campos, pois serão todas as linhas do campo, apesar do cálculo ser realizado linha a linha.

Comment: Então teria como você postar uma exemplo aqui no http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?