# Calcular a diferença de tempo entre um registro e outro na mesma coluna

Tags: mysql

Preciso calcular a diferença de tempo entre um registro e outro, veja que no mesmo dia tenho vários registros e tenho varias pessoas. Não achei nada calculando entre tempos na mesma coluna.

```
SELECT t.nm_primeiro_nome nome,
         ro.tm_check as horario
  from tbl_funcionario t 
  left join tbl_registro ro 
    on t.nr_cracha = ro.nm_registro 
  left join tbl_ordem_diaria od 
    on od.pk_ordem = ro.fk_os
 where od.pk_ordem  is not null
 order by 1,2 desc;
```

---

```
nome    horario
Carlos  26/06/2019 14:09:04
Carlos  26/06/2019 11:42:44
Carlos  26/06/2019 11:10:26
Carlos  26/06/2019 11:04:25
Carlos  26/06/2019 10:58:50
Carlos  26/06/2019 09:43:24
Carlos  26/06/2019 09:39:06
Carlos  26/06/2019 07:50:09
Carlos  26/06/2019 07:41:41
Carlos  26/06/2019 06:13:09
Carlos  19/06/2019 13:59:40
Carlos  19/06/2019 13:12:38
Carlos  19/06/2019 13:07:41
Carlos  19/06/2019 11:42:37
Carlos  19/06/2019 11:11:36
Carlos  19/06/2019 11:10:57
Carlos  19/06/2019 11:07:57
Carlos  19/06/2019 10:03:36
Carlos  19/06/2019 09:57:59
Carlos  19/06/2019 07:35:50
Carlos  19/06/2019 07:26:45
Carlos  19/06/2019 06:17:43
Carlos  17/06/2019 13:18:48
Carlos  17/06/2019 13:08:10
Carlos  17/06/2019 11:42:36
Carlos  17/06/2019 11:10:48
Carlos  17/06/2019 09:24:13
Carlos  17/06/2019 09:09:27
Carlos  13/06/2019 14:00:19
Carlos  13/06/2019 11:10:39
Carlos  13/06/2019 10:39:46
Carlos  13/06/2019 10:13:55
Carlos  13/06/2019 09:37:38
Carlos  13/06/2019 09:30:26
Carlos  13/06/2019 08:22:47
Carlos  13/06/2019 08:14:12
Carlos  13/06/2019 08:06:24
Carlos  11/06/2019 16:23:38
Carlos  11/06/2019 12:16:33
Carlos  11/06/2019 12:11:57
Carlos  11/06/2019 11:44:56
Carlos  11/06/2019 09:53:05
```

Nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43417/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-valores-que-est%C3%A3o-na-mesma-coluna) ele faz a comparação com inteiro eu preciso da diferença entre datas

Comment: você já pesquisou sobre a função **LAG** e **LEAD** ? A função LEAD () e LAG () no MySQL é usada para obter o valor precedente e sucessivo de qualquer linha dentro de sua partição. Essas funções são denominadas como funções não agregadas da janela.

Comment: Você deve usar "Running Total" para fazer essa conta. Veja esse [link](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-calculate-cumulative-sum-running-total-in-mysql/)! (em inglês) e veja se te ajuda.